# does the x86 and x64 options mean anything to a windows phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, x86, 64-bit, anycpu

[image]

As this screen shot shows, we can still choose x86, x64 and anycpu for a windows phone 7 app.
But does it make any difference to the wp7 app?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it, since wp7 runs on ARM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all Windows Phone devices run on 32-bit ARM architecture, the Platform setting there makes no difference.

Comment: thanks, then it's really confusing to still have those options there.